# Linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, continuity

I would like to prove that all linear maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous.

The following definition of continuity is the one I need to use: $f$ is continuous if the inverse image of any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know that being linear means that $f(x+y)$ and $f(ax)=af(x)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$, but how can I use these to prove the above?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the standard basis $e^1,...,e^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can express any linear map $f$ in the form;

$$\\$$

$$f(\textbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} T(e^1) & T(e^2) & \cdots & T(e^n) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x^1 \\ x^2 \\ \vdots \\ x^n \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\\$$
The result of the matrix multiplication is just a polynomial. This is just a special case, but you can see that with respect to any basis you place on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a linear map between finite-dimension vector spaces has the form $L(x) = Ax$ where $A$ is a matrix i.e $L$ is a polynomial; hence continuous.

Comment: How does this use my definition of continuity?

Comment: @PabloDiscobar He reduced your problem to proving that any polynomial satisfies your definition which should be easier.

Comment: @orange_juice I'm sorry, but I don't understand what that means. I'm not sure what this has to do with open subsets

Comment: @PabloDiscobar Can you prove that a polynomial is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Since $f(x+y) =f(x)+f(y)$ it is enough to check continuity at $y=0$.

**Hint 2:** Since $f(ax)=af(x)$ it is enough to check that the preimage of the unit ball centered at $0$ is open.

**Hint 3:** Pick $m= \max\{ \|f(e_j)\| | 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ where $e_j$ is the standard basis.

Now, if $m=0$ you are done. Otherwise, show that the pre-image of the unit ball centered at $0$ contains a ball of radius $\frac{1}{m}$  centered at $0$.

Comment: I''m not sure what you mean by "the pre-image of the unit ball contains a ball of radius 1/m"?

Comment: @PabloDiscobar I mean if $\| u \| \leq \frac{1}{m}$ implies $\|  Tu \| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First a note about linear functions:

$$d(f(ax),f(ay))=d(a f(x), a f(y)) = a \cdot d(x,y)$$

This will come in handy soon. Let us fix $a \in \mathbb R^n$.

---

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open. Then $U$ consists entirely of interior points. i.e. for all $\mathbf x$ in $U$, there is an open neighbourhood $U_{\mathbf x}$ of $\mathbf x$ residing in $U$. Let us take an open ball of radius $R$ around $\mathbf x$ to be this $U_{\mathbf x}$.

$$U_{\mathbf x} = \{\mathbf y : d(\mathbf y, \mathbf x) < R\} \; .$$

Let us now suppose that the preimage of $U_{\mathbf x}$, call it $V_{\mathbf x}$, contains a point that *isn't interior*. Call this point $\mathbf p$. When mapped into $U_{\mathbf x}$, $\mathbf p$ is a certain distance from $x$ less than $R$. This means that
$$R - d(f(\mathbf p), \mathbf x) := r$$
is positive. Well, because there's some wiggle room around where $\mathbf p$ is mapped to, there should be some wiggle room about $\mathbf p$ as well-- i.e. it's an interior point. You could complete this proof with a diagram (recommended) but here's the rest of it in words:

Explicitly construct the set:
$$B_{\mathbf p} = \{\mathbf b : d(\mathbf b - \mathbf p) < r/a\}$$
It will be shown that this set resides in the preimage of $U_{\mathbf x}$, showing that $\mathbf p$ is in fact an interior point.

Each element of $B_{\mathbf p}$, when mapped via $f$, is less than $R$ away from $\mathbf x$ because:
$$\begin{align}
d(f(\mathbf b), \mathbf x) & \leq d(f(\mathbf b), f(\mathbf p)) + d(f(\mathbf p), \mathbf x) \\
&\leq a \cdot d(\mathbf b, \mathbf p) + (R-r) \\
&\leq a \cdot (r/a) + (R - r) \\
&\leq R
\end{align}$$
What this shows is that every point in the preimage of $U_{\mathbf x}$ is itself an interior point of $f^{-1}(U_{\mathbf x})$-- i.e. the preimage of the open set $U_{\mathbf x}$ is open.

Now $U$ is equal to the union of these open neighbourhoods for every point inside:

$$U = \bigcup_{\mathbf x \in U} U_{\mathbf x}$$

So that its preimage is the union of open sets:

$$f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{\mathbf x \in U} f^{-1}(U_{\mathbf x})$$

and so is itself open.

Answer (score 0):

For $x= \left(x_1,\dots, x_n\right)' \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we know $x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i$ where $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$ is the ith entry of x and column vector $e_i$ is 0 except for its ith entry which is 1.  Use the linearity of the mapping, we the would have
$$f(x) =f(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i f(e_i) = \left(f(e_1),\dots, f(e_n) \right) \left(x_1,\dots, x_n\right)' = Ax $$
Then we know $|f(x)-f(x')|=|A(x-x')|$ and continuity follows this clearly.

Comment: What is $A$ exactly?

Comment: If is the same matrix I wrote; $(f(e_1),...., f(e_n))$. You have to remember that $f(e_i)$ is a vector!

Comment: And what is $x'$?

Comment: That is his notation for transpose.

Comment: A is a matrix $ (f(e_1),....,f(e_n)) $ and $'$ is notation for transpose. @PabloDiscobar, as pointed by  FaraadArmwood.

Comment: @pA is $(f(e_1),....,f(e_n))$,